# Let U be a linear operator in a dimensionally finite vector space V. Prove the following

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help, could you tell me how to start this exercise, I don't know how to prove it.

Let U be a linear operator in a dimensionally finite vector space V. Prove the following

$N(U)\subseteq N(U^2)\subseteq ... \subseteq N(U^{k})\subseteq N(U^{k+1})\subseteq ...$

Comment: Given a $v \in N(U),$ $v \in N(U^2)$ because....

Comment: So it would be something like v ∈ N (u)

Then v ∈ N (U) ^ 2
 
by definition v \epsilon   \left \{a\epsilon  V / N (a) = 0 \right \}

Comment: To generalize a bit further, note that this problem has almost nothing to do with linear algebra.  We could similarly consider any set $S$ and any function $f : S \to S$ such that $f(s)=s$ for some $s \in S$.  Then defining $f^k = f \circ \cdots \circ f$ ($k>0$ copies of $f$), we may show $$f^{-1}(s) \subseteq (f^2)^{-1}(s) \subseteq \cdots \subseteq (f^k)^{-1}(s) \subseteq (f^{k+1})^{-1}(s) \subseteq \cdots$$ (which immediately implies your result by setting $f=U, S = V, s = 0$)

Comment: The problem doesn't require finite dimensionality of the vector space, in line with what @BrianMoehring said about generalizing.  However finite dimensionality guarantees that the nested inclusions "stabilize" to equality of sets by the time $k$ reaches the dimension of the vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in N(U)$, $Ux=0$ and then $U^2(x)=U(Ux)=U(0)=0$ so $x\in N(U^2)$

Just generalize this.

Comment: ok, I think I already have it, let x be an arbitrary element of N (u) as x∈ N (U) then Ux = 0 and now as U ^ 2 we see it as U (u (x)) = U (0) = 0 therefore x ∈ N (U ^ 2)

then N (U) would be contained in N (U ^ 2)

and so with the other N (U ^ k)

Comment: That is right..

Comment: thanks u, you really helped me  :)))